# relative_url_root in ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

What's the equivalent of `relative_url_root` in ActionMailer?

I've tried setting it up in `default_url_options`, but it appends the parameter in the query string.

Adding `:skip_relative_url_root = false` doesn't work either.

Using `:host = 'somehost.com/subdir'` **does** work, but is that appropriate?

Thanks!

Comment: it's not the same between your mailer and you app ?

Comment: It is the same, but ActionMailer doesn't seem to pick up the configuration option.

Answer (score 3):

A cleaner way to do it :

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
        :host => "somehost.com",
        :only_path => false,
        :script_name => "/subdir"
    }
```

[Source](http://www.stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/code-snippets/actionmailer-link-for-a-rails-app-deployed-in-a-sub-directory/)

Comment: the :only_path => false actually did the trick for me. What's the meaning of that parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Use `script_name` option into `default_url_options` of `ActionMailer::Base`. Based on [this article](http://www.bitherd.com/wp/?p=109).